# TypeScript constructor overload does not recognize the type

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, angular-test

There is a back-end service (auto-generated from the Swagger, cannot be modified):

```
public getFoo(account: string, name: string, observe?: 'body', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<Foo>;
public getFoo(account: string, name: string, observe?: 'response', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<HttpResponse<Foo>>;
public getFoo(account: string, name: string, observe?: 'events', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<HttpEvent<Foo>>;
public getFoo(account: string, name: string, observe: any = 'body', reportProgress: boolean = false ): Observable<any> {
```

Trying to write Angular test:

```
backendServiceSpyObj = jasmine.createSpyObj('BackendService', ['getFoo']);
backendServiceSpyObj.getFoo.and.returnValue(of(mockedFoo));
```

Now this fails:

```
Argument of type 'Observable<Foo>' is not assignable to parameter of type Observable<HttpEvent<Foo>>'.
```

Any clues how to make TypeScript linter now that the `Observable<Foo>` is expected instead?

Comment: There are 4 diff return type for same method .. You can use `useClass` . [You can refer this article](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49) in which I have tried to cover this type of scenario

Comment: Can you provide the `component` file to help you further on this

Comment: You cannot do polymorphism with Typescript. All you can do is optionnal parameters. Can you be more explicit on how `getFoo` declaration is expected to work (showing the whole class maybe) ?